# Boot external Windows 8.1 installation on Mac Book Pro Retina 2015

Tags: macos, windows, external-disk

In the past I’ve been able to run Windows 8.1 on a Mac Book Pro Retina Mid 2012 installed on an external hard drive using WinToUsb. I had OSX Mavericks installed on the internal drive.
After turning on the machine I could simply press „Alt“ to see all bootable drives currently connected. I could then select the Windows drive to boot into it.
I could even boot into it on another Mac Book Pro Retina Mid 2012 running first Mountain Lion and then Yosemite using the same procedure.

I now bought a new Mac Book Pro Retina 15“ Mid 2015 and tried to boot into Windows, but the drive doesn’t show up next to the OSX drive.
<s>I’m now wondering what causes this and only know the hardware has changed and it came with Yosemite preinstalled.</s>

How can I fix this and is it still possible to use external Windows drives with this new Mac at all? <s>What exactly is causing this, the new hardware or operating system?</s>

Apple support couldn’t help and say they only support Boot Camp installations on internal drives. Installing to the internal drive is no option for me, since I would like to keep the old Windows installation without reinstalling and I like to save the expensive internal SSD space.

Thanks a lot in advance!

## Update

I had the chance to test on another Mac Book Pro Retina Mid 2012 which was just updated to Yosemite. I could successfully boot into the external Windows installation on this machine. I therefore guess it's a change in hardware and not Yosemite causing the issue.